# Let $A_1\le A$ and $A_2\unlhd A$. Since $A_2$ is normal in $A$, it is also normal in $A_1 \cdot A_2$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

The set up of the problem is as follows.

> Let $A_1, A_2$ be subgroups of a group $A$ and $A_2$ is normal in $A$. Define $A_1 \cdot A_2$ as the subset of elements of the form $a_1 \cdot a_2$ where $a_1 \in A_1$ and $a_2 \in A_2$. Since $A_2$ is normal in $A$, it is also normal in $A_1 \cdot A_2$.

The proof I have in mind for this, I believe, trivializes the problem, so I think I must be doing something wrong, especially since normality is not "transitive."

> I need to show that for all $b \in A_1 \cdot A_2$ and $g \in A_2$, $bgb^{-1} \in A_2$. As $A_1 \cdot A_2 \subset A$, we can regard $bgb^{-1}$ as conjugation by an element $b$ in $A$. Since $A_2$ is normal in $A$, $bgb^{-1} \in A_2$.

Have I trivialized the problem, or is this proof on the right track?

Comment: The problem as stated is in fact trivial. It is more interesting to show that $A_1\cdot A_2$ is a group.

Comment: @subrosar Is it trivial in the sense that the proof I wrote down is fine? I already managed to show that $A_1 \cdot A_2$ is a group.

Comment: What you wrote is very close. The last expression should be $bgb^{-1}\in A_2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your proof (which now concludes with "$bgb^{-1}\in A_2$") is fine. It does not use transitivity of normality, since that is

> $H\unlhd K$, $K\unlhd G$ imply $H\unlhd G$.

The structure of the question is different.